# High Sierra installation is stuck and can't boot on the Yosemite OS as previously

Tags: macos, hard-drive, high-sierra

I was installing macOS High Sierra on a old MacBook Air (more than 12 years) with Yosemite. But it didn't work, it shows, during the installation, a message like this:

[image]

However doing that it didn't work, it showed this screen

[image]

Clicking on restart it goes again the loading screen:

[image]

and after this screen it goes again to the High Sierra installation:

[image]

The installation fails again (image 1), and it keeps in this loop and so can't boot on the Yosemit OS as previously.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: If your MacBook supports internet recovery, try it!

Comment: Also tried that but same issue! Thanks